# df.loc[] not working for variables row,col

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting an error when trying to use `df.loc[]` with iterating through rows and columns of my dataframe. Here is the code:

```
TP_list = [0]
FP_list = [0]
for col in df.columns:
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    for row in df.iterrows():
        if df.loc[row, col].str.startswith('C') == True:
            if df.loc[row,col] == 1:
                TP += 1
        else:
            if df.loc[row, col] == 1:
                FP += 1
    TP_list.append(TP)
    FP_list.append(FP)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `row` is not a row index, it's a tuple `(index, series)`. Use `df.loc[row[0], col]`

Answer (score 0):

Each 'row' returned by `df.iterrows()` is in fact a Series. So you cannot use it as an argument in `df.loc`.

You may be able to use iloc in tandem with range(len(df)) instead.